# Computing DIC and Bayes factor in R

Tags: r, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, logit, bayes-factors

How can I compute the DIC value and Bayesfactor value for a bayesian glm model? (for both models or even just 1 of the models)

I have 2 models I would like to compare.
1. `bayesglm` model (using `arm` package)
2. `logit` model (bayesian logistic regression model using `bayeslogit` package)

the explanatory variables are both continuous and categorical
the response is binary (0/1)
same dataset

Both models give predictions of between 0 and 1.

Comment: use brms and compare models with LOO or WAIC, each of which is preferable to DIC.

Comment: do you mean to form new models using the brms package and then compare instead of using the arm and bayeslogit packages?

Comment: Yes. I take it you are using two packages because each has limited capabilities. In brms, I am sure you can fit both models in the same package, which more easily allows for model comparison.

Comment: oh no, I am using 2 packages because I couldn't decide which package to use and I came to a conclusion I will do a comparison between packages as my research topic. I was stuck between picking a BIC(variable selected) model which has 9 predictors or the original model that had 12 predictors so wanted to compute the bayes factor and DIC to help me decide the model to use from each package.

Comment: Ok. It is probably not the best idea to compare packages, unless you also do simulations. For example, if you have real data, you can never know which has better performance. in contrast, simulations allow to know the truth by assuming values, from which you can determine the optimal model.

Comment: I was originally planning to use the large dataset I have to check the prediction accuracy of each models and using the testing dataset aswell. I have quite a large dataset 30000+ observations. After using both packages, the results of the coefficient estimates were really similar